# Reason for table that only references 2 other tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For a coursework I have, I have been given some example (Postgres) SQL code for a Vinyl shop.

Part of the database is an `album` table, for storing information about an album (title, genre, etc.) and an `artist` table, which is used for storing information about an albums arist (name, genre).

You can see the code I am dealing with below:

```sql
create table album
(
    albumID varchar(8) primary key,
    album_title varchar(50) not null,
    album_genre varchar(20) not null,
    album_label varchar(25) not null,
    album_catalogue_no varchar(15) not null,
    album_release_date varchar(4) not null,
    album_type varchar(10) not null
);

create table artist
(
    artistID varchar(8) primary key,
    artist_name varchar(40) not null,
    artist_genre varchar(20) not null
);

create table albumartist
(
    primary key (albumID, artistID),
    albumID varchar(8) references album(albumID),
    artistID varchar(8) references artist(artistID)
);
```

What I am struggling to understand, is why `albumartist` exists?

Wouldn't it just be easier to have `artistID` in the `album` table?

(Before someone says it, I can't contact my lecturer at this moment, which is the reason why I am asking on here)

Comment: What if an album has more than one artist on it?

Comment: @jmoerdyk That would make sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on that comment, the table `albumartist` is an [Associative Entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity), meaning that it acts as a many-to-many bridge between the `artist` and `album` tables. By adding this juntion table, it allows one album to have more than one artist, and one artist to have more than one album.

Looking at your definition of the `albumartist` table, I would be inclined to change it to this, because there is no purpose having a row in that table with `null` values:

```
create table albumartist
(
    primary key (albumID, artistID),
    albumID varchar(8) not null references album(albumID),
    artistID varchar(8) not null references artist(artistID)
);
```